# Replace data in dataframe with newest sheet in the loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have multiple sheets in the same format and want to combine all the data into one sheet. Ther is a new sheet every month a few new rows are added per month, as well as some of the data, could change.

Example

```
Sheet (May)        Sheet (June)
ID   Text          ID  Text 
122  A             122 A
123  ABB           123 EXX
124  SOL           124 SOL
                   125 NRP
```

Desired dataframe

```
 df
 ID  Text
 122 A
 123 EXX
 124 SOL
 125 NRP
```

This is the code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

glob.glob("C:/Users/Desktop/Data/*.xlsx")

asset_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Text'])

for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/Desktop/Data/*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, usecols="B,C")
    asset_data ['Text'] = df['Text']


asset_data.describe()
asset_data.head()
asset_data.to_excel("AOMNames.xlsx")
print(asset_data)
```

Disclaimer: I am a total noob with Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use merge function of pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[122,123,124,125],
                    'Text':['A','EXX','SOL','NRP']
                    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[122,123,124],
    'Text':['A','ABB','SOL']})


mergeddf=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left', on=['id','Text'])
print(mergeddf)
```

**Output**

```
    id  Text
0   122 A
1   123 EXX
2   124 SOL
3   125 NRP
```

Now you can use pandas function to save the dataframe as excel.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this does not solve the scenario where the new dataframe overrides older dataframe with new information. See **ID 123** in the example above where text changes from **ABB** to **EXX**